# Drop down list to PHP SQL DATABASE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, database

how can i get the txttrackid to the database, it only get the one from dropdown list

```
<label><b>Track/Section</b></label></br>
<select id="soflow" name="track_type" onChange="add1()">

  <option value="">Select Tracks</option>
  <option value="ABM">ABM</option>
  <option value="STEM">STEM</option>
  <option va;lue="ICT">ICT</option>
  <option value="HAS">HAS</option>
  <option value="BM">BM</option>
  <option value="HUMMS">HUMMS</option>
</select>

<input id="txttrackid" class="txttrackid" name="txttrackid" type="text"> </br>
```

and here is the Javascript code

```
   <script>
      function add1() { 
      var ddlvalue = document.getElementById("soflow").value;
      var up1 = document.getElementById("txttrackid");
      //console.log(ddlvalue);
      if (ddlvalue == 'ABM')
        up1.value = '1';
      else if (ddlvalue == 'STEM')
        up1.value = '2';
      else if (ddlvalue == 'ICT')
        up1.value = '3';
      else if (ddlvalue == 'HAS')
        up1.value = '4';
      else if (ddlvalue == 'BM')
        up1.value = '5';
      else if (ddlvalue == 'HUMMS')
        up1.value = '6';

    }

    </script>
```

only the one from dropdown list shows when i enter it in the database

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the code, its easier getting the setting the values on select then use when you need them

```js
 
      function add1() { 
      var selval=$("#soflow").val();//get the value of the select box on select
      if(selval !=""){//if the value is not empty 
      $("#txttrackid").val(selval);//set the value in txttrackid
      }
      

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><b>Track/Section</b></label></br>
<select id="soflow" name="track_type" onChange="add1()">

  <option value="">Select Tracks</option>
  <option value="1">ABM</option>
  <option value="2">STEM</option>
  <option value="3">ICT</option>
  <option value="4">HAS</option>
  <option value="5">BM</option>
  <option value="6">HUMMS</option>
</select>
<input id="txttrackid" class="txttrackid" name="txttrackid" type="text"> </br>
```